# Drools : applying same rules on all attributes

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools, we are trying to create basic validation rules like a NULL check, etc. using the Drools n Scala framework.

I have a source file which has 200 attributes, need to apply NULL-check rule on all these attributes,
is there any easy way to do this? or do I need to create 200 rules for each attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a POJO ("plain old java object", getters/setters and some private variables to hold values) or modern java Records (effectively the same thing), then the answer is no: you need separate rules. For this scenario, the only way to check that field "name" is null is to actually assert against that field like this:

```
rule "example - name is null"
when
  ExampleObject( name == null )
then
  System.out.println("Name is null.");
end
```

However there exist other data structures -- for example, Map and its sibling types -- where you can reference the fields by name. In this case you could theoretically iterate through all of the field names and find the one whose value is empty.

So, for example, `Map` has a `keySet()` method which returns a set of fields -- you could iterate through this keyset and for each key check that there is a non-null value present in the map.

```
rule "example with map"
when
  $map: Map()
  $keys: Set() from $map.keySet()

  $key: String() from $keys
  String( this == null ) from $map.get($key)
  
  // or this might work, not sure if the "this" keyword allows this syntax:
  // Map( this[$key] == null ) from $map
then
  System.out.println($key + " is missing/null");
end
```

This would require converting your Java object into a Map before passing into the rules.

However I **DO NOT RECOMMEND** this approach. Maps are *extremely* un-performant in rules because of how they serialize/deserialize. You will use a *ton* of unnecessary heap when firing them. If you look at how a HashMap serializes, for example, by peeking at its source code you'll see that it actually contains a bunch of "child" data structures like entryset and keyset and things like that. When using "new", those child structures are only initialized if and when you need them; but when serializing/deserializing, they're created immediately even if you don't need them.

---

Another solution would be to use Java reflection to get the list of declared field names, and then iterate through those names using reflection to get the value out for that field. In your place I'd do this in Java (reflection is problematic enough without trying to do it in Drools) and then if necessary invoke such a utility function from Drools.